# why cannot be cast FragmentActivity to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

Tags: android

after updated android studio sdk 29 ,every dependency start x and every fragment is also x
why cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

holder.catImage.setOnClickListener(view -> {

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        SubCategoryFragment subCategoryFragment = new SubCategoryFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("catId",arrayList.get(position).getId());
        bundle.putString("catname",arrayList.get(position).getName());
        Log.e("cbvhgfdsghd",arrayList.get(position).getId());
        subCategoryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main, subCategoryFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("main");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    });
```

---

```
2019-07-27 12:24:39.417 4307-4307/com.lgt.O7grocers E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lgt.O7grocers, PID: 4307
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
        at com.lgt.O7grocers.Adapter.MainCatAdapter$1.onClick(MainCatAdapter.java:63)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6710)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6668)
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:797)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26450)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7172)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing `getApplicationContext()` or `getApplication()`. Make sure that the context is an Activity context.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Context you are using here is an Activity context means getActivity().

If you are passing getActivity() as context, then it won't crash.
#HappyCoding!!